# Mocking Sentry with Jest Framework in Typescript/NodeJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, jestjs

I am trying to implement Sentry in my existing NodeJS project, and there's one piece of Sentry code that I am unable to mock.

My Sentry code is below:

```js
const app: express.Express = express();

Sentry.init({
    dsn: process.env.SENTRY_DSN_SERVER,
    serverName: process.env.SERVER_NAME,
    environment: process.env.NODE_ENV,
    tracesSampleRate: 1.0,
    integrations: [
        new RewriteFrames({
            root: global.__dirname,
        }),
    ],
});


app.use(Sentry.Handlers.requestHandler()); // Newly added line 1
app.use(Sentry.Handlers.tracingHandler()); // Newly added line 2

... (more route codes follow)
```

When I try to mock Sentry, I use this in `setup-pretest.ts`

```js
jest.mock("@sentry/node", () => ({
    init: () => jest.fn(),
}));
jest.mock("@sentry/integrations");
jest.mock("@sentry/tracing", () => () => jest.fn());
```

The above **jest** code works when the two newly added lines are removed.

I have tried mocking **Handlers** value to return

```js
jest.mock("@sentry/node", () => ({
    init: () => jest.fn(),
     Handlers: () => {
        return {
            requestHandler: () => jest.fn(),
            tracingHandler: () => jest.fn(),
        };
    },
}));

jest.mock("@sentry/integrations");
jest.mock("@sentry/tracing", () => () => jest.fn());
```

This fails with the error: **Sentry.Handlers.requestHandler is not a function**

Comment: Your test double makes no sense - Handlers isn’t being _called_ in the implementation.

Comment: @jonrsharpe they are being called as middleware functions, I was able to make them work with my below change.

Answer (score 0):

I had to mock them each individually to make it to work

```js
jest.mock("@sentry/node", () => ({
    init: () => jest.fn(),
    Handlers: () =>
        jest.fn((req, res, next) => {
            next();
        }),
}));
Sentry.Handlers.requestHandler = () =>
    jest.fn((req, res, next) => {
        next();
    });
Sentry.Handlers.tracingHandler = () =>
    jest.fn((req, res, next) => {
        next();
    });
```